# Can't select another row in ASP.NET GridView (first selection works) because __doPostBack script is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a problem with a GridView in an ASP.NET web forms application. Basically what happens is that I have code in place to select a row by clicking on it, which works only the first click. When clicking on other rows, nothing happens and in the browser console I get `__doPostBack is undefined` errors.

The code to allow row selection is mostly based on handling the `OnRowDataBound` event, which looks like this in my case:

```
protected void gvUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gvUsers, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

And the following is what I do in the selection changing event handler:

```
protected void gvUsers_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvUsers.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    row.CssClass = "selectedUser";
}
```

Nothing special really. This works for lots of people. But when I inspect the HTML that is returned by the server after the handling of this event, indeed the `__doPostBack` script is missing, as well as the two hidden `input`s it uses.

Comment: What does your `ScriptManager` definition look like? Also, what is your `UnobtrusiveValidationMode` set to in your web.config?

Comment: @JimMSDN I do not have an explicitly defined `ScriptManager` and I do not have `UnobstrusiveValidationMode` in my web.config either.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps one or the other, if defined/set, might be creating some unexpected behavior (I'm tracking down something like this myself...).  One interesting test might be to add a ScriptManager and see if the observed behavior changes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I won't know the reason why `__doPostBack` is not defined after changing row selection any time soon, but the workaround for now is to 'force' the generation of this function in a standard fashion (lots of people have had various underlying reasons to do this):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gvUsers, "");

    //other logic
}
```

It seems like certain rare circumstances trigger weird bugs in the ASP.NET framework concerning the `__doPostBack` function.